# Accessing an instance of a class in an arraylist loop

Tags: java, class, arraylist, instance

So I have a class LayerCopper that holds a few textboxes and a few methods to set values in those textboxes:

```
public class LayerCopper extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public LayerCopper() {
initComponents();
}

private static javax.swing.JFormattedTextField CuWeightTextField;
private static javax.swing.JFormattedTextField LayerNumJFormattedTextField;

...
...
...

public void setLayerNumberText(int layerNumber) {
LayerNumJFormattedTextField.setText("" + layerNumber);
}

public void setLayerCuThickness(double CuThickness) {
CuWeightTextField.setValue(CuThickness);
}

}
```

I also have another class StackupCalculator with multiple instances of the LayerCopper panels in it. I have an arraylist that holds each instance of the LayerCopper panel:

```
static ArrayList<LayerCopper> layerSet_Copper = new ArrayList<>();

...
...
...

public void createLayerSetArray() {

  layerSet_Copper.add(layerCopper1);
  layerSet_Copper.add(layerCopper2);
  layerSet_Copper.add(layerCopper3);
  layerSet_Copper.add(layerCopper4);
  layerSet_Copper.add(layerCopper5);

  initializeLayerArrayValues();
}
```

When my initializeLayerArrayValues runs, It's supposed to populate a couple textfields with text:

```
private void initializeLayerArrayValues() {
for (int i = 0; i < layerSet_Copper.size(); i++) {      
    layerSet_Copper.get(i).setLayerNumberText(i + 1);
    layerSet_Copper.get(i).setLayerCuThickness(0.750);
}
}
```

When I run the program though it doesn't update the fields. I'm guessing I am calling the main class LayerCopper and not the instanced version of it? How would I call the instanced version of the layer?

Comment: We need more code to test ourself, how are the JTextFields added to the panel ? How is the panel rendered ? what is in initComponents ?

Comment: try changing CuWeightTextField and LayerNumJFormattedTextField to non static if you want to set their values differently in different layerCopperX

Comment: Ah dang, That was it. I had my textfields set to static. Changing them to non-static fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

According to you, you haven't instantiated `LayerCopper`. You need to make a new instance of it, and make `layerCopper1`, `layerCopper2`, etc. Then use `createLayerSetArray()`.

Like so:

```
LayerCopper lc = new LayerCopper();
// create values different layerCoppers to go in layerSet_Copper
lc.createLayerSetArray();
```

I don't quite understand the inner workings of your class, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the textfields from static to non-static fixed it for me. /cheers